# Traverse a "tree" dynamically given number of levels

Tags: c#, .net, list, recursion, collections

I have an object called `Team` that has a property `Children` which represents a list of "sub teams" under that team

```
public class Team
{
    public List<Team> Children {get;set;}
}
```

I currently have some code that does this to build up a single list of all teams but as you can see its "hard coded" in terms of "levels" it goes down:

```
Team topTeam = GetTopteam();
List<Team> allTeams = new List<Team>();
allTeams.Add(topTeam);
allTeams.AddRange(topTeam.Children);

var childrensChildren = topTeam.Children.SelectMany(r=>r.Children);                   
allTeams.AddRange(childrensChildren);
```

and it keeps going  . .

I now want to make the "levels" configurable so something like this:

```
 public IEnumerable<Team> GetTeams(int numberOfLevelsDown)
 {
 }
```

- If I pass in 1, i only return a list of the topteam and its direct children.
- If I pass in 2, I get the top team, the children and the children's children

and so on . . .

What is the most elegant way of traversing down levels in a tree dynamically?

Comment: Why not recursion with decrementing `numberOfLevelsDown` on each level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion to do this.

This kind of method signature is because of performance issues and it prevents generating a lot of intermediate lists.

```
public void GetTeams(List<Team> teams, Team team, int level)
{
    if (level == 0)
        return;

    if (team.Children == null)
        return;

    foreach (var t in team.Children)
    {
        teams.Add(t);
        GetTeams(teams, t, level - 1);
    }
}
```

and use it like this

```
var list = new List<Team>();
Team topTeam = GetTopteam();
GetTeams(list, topTeam, 5);
//now you have teams in list
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this kind of thing many times.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> EnumerateDescendants<T>(this T root, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> children)
{
    yield return root;
    foreach (var child in children(root).SelectMany(x => x.EnumerateDescendants(children)))
    {
        yield return child;
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var allTeams = rootTeam.EnumerateDescendants(x => x.Children);
```

You should be able to modify it something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> EnumerateDescendants<T>(this T root, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> children, int maxLevels, int currentLevel = 0)
{
    if (currentLevel <= maxLevels)
    {
        yield return root;
        foreach (var child in children(root).SelectMany(x => x.EnumerateDescendants(children, maxLevels, currentLevel + 1)))
        {
            yield return child;
        }
    }
}
```

You should be able to use it like this:

```
var allTeamsUpToLevel2 = rootTeam.EnumerateDescendants(x => x.Children, 2);
```

I may have the >= mixed up but something like this should work.